# Compiling Lua 5.2 alpha under VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lua

I'd like to compile Lua 5.2 alpha under visual studio but I'm getting errors and I have no clue how to fix them.

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
error LNK2005: _main already defined in lua.obj
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could guide me through the creation of a VS2010 solution for Lua 5.2 alpha, or point me to related resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/readme.html#other

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are most probably compiling both `luac.c` and `lua.c` in one VS project. To build Lua yourself in VS you need three projects:

library - this should be either DLL or static library project. Should include every .c file under src/ **except** `luac.c` and `lua.c`. You only need this if you are embedding.

compiler - console executable, containing `luac.c`

interpreter - console executable, containing `lua.c`

Comment: @Raine, this is documented in http://www.lua.org/work/doc/#other which is included in the tarball.

Comment: @lhf, thank you. I'm working on a .net Lua interpreter following your C source. I had to put DLR-based IronLua on hold. Lua is strangely difficult to port on .net.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you included lua.c, or luac.c, with another program.  Each of these is a separate program with their own main.  You need to include just one of them to build the standalone Lua component, or neither if you're embedding Lua in your own application.

Answer (score 0):

The Lua source distribution includes a console interpreter, which already defines `main`, and you don't want that. Just look in the Lua source and delete or comment out the `main`s that you find.