# Line Suppression State Error LNK2005 _main already defined in lua.obj

Tags: c++, c, lua

Im trying to compile a dll for my my game and i get these 2 errors upon compiling

Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found (im assuming this will go away after error 2 is fixed)

and
Error   LNK2005 _main already defined in lua.obj

i know i could probably fix it by making main Static but how do i even open the OBJ files they aren't under source files or anything

and when i double click on the errors it doesn't direct me to the underlined code as it usually does so im stuck oof

Comment: im using visual studio 2017 btw

Comment: Maybe you should ask the overwatch team how you can edit the question to add this information, instead of having it in a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling Lua 5.2 alpha under VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321927/compiling-lua-5-2-alpha-under-vs2010)

Answer (score 2):

Was using lua.c and luac.c deleted luac.c and worked fine